# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ with the finite complement topology is not Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ with the finite complement topology is not Hausdorff. 
What are the closures of the following two subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the finite complement topology? (Fully justify your answers.)
i) $A=\{1,2,3\}$ $\,\,\,\,\,$ ii) $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,4,...\}$

$\textbf{Proof:}$ By way of contradiction, assume $\mathbb{Z}$ with the finite complement topology is Hausdorff. Then $\forall a \neq b \,\, \exists U,V \subset \mathbb{Z}$ where $U \cap V = \emptyset$ with $a \in U$, $b \in V$, and $U,V$ are open sets.

Since $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then pick $a=0$ and $b=1$. Since $U,V \subset \mathbb{Z}$ are open in the finite complement topology, then $U^c$,$V^c$ are finite. 
Thus, $U,V$ are infinite. So $V \not \subset U^c$. Since $1 \in V$, then $1 \not \in V^c$, so $1 \in (U^c)^c=U$ by infinite/finite sets.

But, $U \cap V = \emptyset$. $\rightarrow \leftarrow$ (contradiction!)

$\therefore$ By way of contradiction, $\mathbb{Z}$ with the finite complement topology is not Hausdorff.

(i) $A=\{1,2,3\}$ 
$A \subset \mathbb{Z}$ with the finite complement topology. So, $\mathbb{Z}\backslash A$ is open $\implies A$ is closed.

$\therefore A=\overline{A}$.

(ii) $\overline{\mathbb{N}}=\mathbb{N} \cup \mathbb{N}^{'}=\mathbb{N}$ where $\mathbb{N}^{'}$ is the set of all limit points of $\mathbb{N}$.

---

I am checking if my proof is valid and could use any feedback on it.
Any help with part (ii) would be nice. I am unsure how to provide a further explanation.

Comment: A closed set must either be finite or the whole space. The closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing that set. What does this tell you about $\overline{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins So can we say since $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, then the smallest closed space must be the whole space $\mathbb{N}$? Thus why we have the closure of $\mathbb{N}$ is equal to $\mathbb{N}$? i.e. $\overline{\mathbb{N}}=\mathbb{N} \cup \mathbb{N}^{'}=\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof that the space is not Hausdorff is correct, but there is no need to use proof by contradiction. Let $m$ and $n$ be distinct integers, and let $U$ and $V$ be open nbhds of $m$ and $n$, respectively; there are finite sets $F,G\subseteq\Bbb Z$ such that $U=\Bbb Z\setminus F$ and $V=\Bbb Z\setminus G$. Then

$$U\cap V=(\Bbb Z\setminus F)\cap(\Bbb Z\setminus G)=\Bbb Z\setminus(F\cup G)\ne\varnothing\,,$$

since $F\cup G$ is finite. Thus, $m$ and $n$ do not have disjoint open nbhds. (I could just as well have worked with a specific pair of integers, but it’s just as easy to make the argument for an arbitrary pair and prove the stronger result that **no** two distinct points can be separated by disjoint open sets.)

For part (ii) you can prove the stronger result that every infinite subset of $\Bbb Z$ is dense in $\Bbb Z$, i.e., has closure equal to $\Bbb Z$. Suppose that $A\subseteq\Bbb Z$ is infinite. Let $n\in\Bbb Z$. If $U$ is an open nbhd of $n$, $\Bbb Z\setminus U$ is finite, so $A\nsubseteq\Bbb Z\setminus U$, and therefore $U\cap A\ne\varnothing$. Thus, $n\in\operatorname{cl}A$, and since $n$ was an arbitrary integer, $\operatorname{cl}A=\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Any infinite set with the cofinite topology is $T_1$ but not $T_2$.  The proof that it is not Hausdorff is given, in essence,  by @BrianM.Scott above. (The gist of the argument is that two cofinite subsets of an infinite set have to intersect nontrivially.)

For part $ii)$ you need a correction: $\bar{\Bbb N}=\Bbb Z$.  The only proper closed subsets are the finite ones.